# Is There A Way to Maintain/Keep Calendar Event History?

Tags: sharepoint-calendar

We have a calendar that manages our ongoing production support releases and we are noticing that the Calendar does not keep the history in the calendar. It only keeps a month or two of past history until we move forward and the system automatically deletes past events. Is there a way to change a setting to make the calendar maintain the history of events/releases?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you mean by History of calendar event?

I have calendar on my team sites, i can see all the events from last 3 years( since it created). No issue at all.

I think check your calendar, if their is any workflow or event receiver or custom feature deployed which is deleting the old records from the calendar.

Another thing which cause this issue is Retention Policy, check if that is enabled on the calendar list.

Comment: Happy for you that you can go backwards and see your history. However, in our case, when you try going backwards in a SharePoint Calendar, you only see the prior month's history of events on the calendar and then nothing after that.

Also, we recently added an alert on the calendar to know when changes/updates are made, and in doing so, we are getting alerts that the "system" is deleting older events that are older than 30 days... so appears that somewhere we need to adjust a setting... hence my question.

Comment: There are no workflows, event receivers, or custom features deployed that would be effecting this... we are just now slowly starting to work more with SharePoint as most stuff has been OTB usage.   Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any retention policy on the your Site collection which deleteing the old entries from calendar?

Comment: From what I can see there are no policies of any sort in place. The base setup was done several years ago and we've just rolled with it... We have adjusted some settings such as file size limits for uploading... but nothing has been put in place to "limit" anything such as the Calendars maintaining entered events.

Comment: how many items in the calendar? check this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e48c8038-ab7e-4465-8c76-353624743db8/sp2010-calendar-list-view-threshold-remove-old-items?forum=sharepointdevelopment . their is something which is causing this deletion, either a workflow, retention policy or some custom code? is your calendar sync with outlook or overlay calendar?

Comment: Great insight!! I see that "Enable Retention" is active... however, there is no Actions defined... so assuming that it is using some standard built in Action for the OTB install. If I were to deactivate the "Enable Retention" feature, will that resolve the issue? The actual term is contradictory to what is happening is seems... Please advise.

Comment: that is what i believe, you can also check under the calendar list settings and information management policy.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Waqas Sarwar for the help... I finally identified where the retention action was applied and removed it.... Did not find it on other calendars created but for some reason one had been applied by someone to this particular calendar in question... So hopefully going forward we will be good.